# How to replace app icon in top bar of ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, icons, top-bar

I'm currently developing an icon theme and need some guidance on how to locate and modify the black and white icons for the Files app, or for any other app, for that matter.

Could anyone point me in the direction of the particular directory where these icons are stored? Also, is there a standard naming system I should follow for this kind of secondary app icon?

Thank you for your time.

[image: Files app black and white icon]

Comment: Hi, as a start, those are regular icons but some saturation is applied. can you try this extension and see if the icon you are looking for is the same. Otherwise we can move to dig it further. The extension is https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4408/app-menu-icon-remove-symbolic/

Comment: Also this app-menu is removed in latest version of GNOME, V45

Comment: @PRATAP thank you so much for your time. I used your extension, and I was able to change the top-bar-icon. However, I was wondering how I can place 2 different icons for my app, one in the normal task bar and one in the top-bar. Currently, I only have a single .desktop file which I moved into /usr/share/applications, but this affects both top bar and task bar. 

I added a new screenshot here https://app.screencast.com/XgzBuucfoeAYX?conversation=34TCGziHRWA3Hguh7kezdU

Comment: If you have a different question, open a dedicated question for it. Here, you asked to modify the icon on the Application menu button.

Comment: @Chiggiddi I think if you want to have the icon on topbar different from `.desktop` file. It is quite difficult to achieve. But if you want to, may I know how many Icons/apps are there?

Comment: @Chiggiddi this may help you https://developer-old.gnome.org/icon-theme-spec/

Comment: @PRATAP thank you kindly for your input. I didn't think it to be so difficult as the default apps such as flysoft, files app and the others also provide a secondary app icon in the top bar. I will take a look at your link and see where it leads me. Thanks, once again!

Comment: Hi, I have made an workaround for it. The trick is for the secondary app icon, add `-symbolic.<ext name>` in you icon theme. for example if you nave `org.gnome.Nautilus.svg`, `org.gnome.Nautilus-symbolic.svg`. This way you dont need to change the icon name in .desktop file. Though you may need to study the link above for the priority.

Comment: Try above with out the extension. The saturation may be removed if need by tweaking the extension. I tried without extension for the secondary icon and it worked.

Comment: @PRATAP Wow, simply wow. I tried so many things and didn't achieve any result. With -symbolic.<ext name> I made it work! I will mark your answer as correct! Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app menu icon has a style_class `app-menu-icon`.
And the default/majority of themes have below styling for it.

```
#panel .panel-button .app-menu-icon {
  -st-icon-style: symbolic; }
```

This way the icon mentioned in the `.desktop` file, for example
`org.gnome.Nautilus` will look for `org.gnome.Nautilus-symbolic`.

So for the secondary icon/top bar app-menu-icon, if you have `-symbolic.<ext>` in you icon-theme, that will be used.

The priorities are a big topic IMHO. you may go through it here https://developer-old.gnome.org/icon-theme-spec/.